# How to immediately update a state in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm struggling with this problem and I've already tried many solutions but none of them fit me.

I have a context that I use to share information that I get from an API. I will summarize the files for you:

```js
file: useGetInfo.tsx
    
    type InfoContextData = { ... }
    
    type Props = { ... }

    type InfoResponseProps = { ... }
    
    export const InfoContext = createContext<InfoContextData>({} as InfoContextData)
    
    export const InformationProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
        const isBrowser = typeof window !== `undefined`

        const [infoStorage, setInfoStorage] = useState(
            isBrowser && localStorage.getItem('info')
                ? String(localStorage.getItem('info'))
                : undefined
        )

        const [result, setResult] = useState<InfoResponseProps | null>(null)

        const getInfo = useCallback(async (value: string) => {
            const url = `<URL_FROM_API${value}>`

            await axios.get(url)
                .then((response) => {
                    setResult(response.data)
                })
                .catch((_) => {
                    setResult(null)
                })
        })

        useEffect(() => {
            if (!infoStorage) {
                return
            }

            getInfo(infoStorage)
        }, [infoStorage, getInfo])

        return (
            <InfoContext.Provider
                value={{
                    result,
                    setResult,
                    infoStorage,
                    setInfoStorage,
                    getInfo,
                }}
            >
                {children}
            </InfoContext.Provider>
        )
    }
```

Then in the component I call the context:

```js
file: SomeComponent.tsx

    const Component = () => {
        const { setInfoStorage, getInfo, result } = useContext(InfoContext)
        const [input, setInput] = useState('')

        const handleInfoSubmit = useCallback(() => {
            getInfo(input)

            if (!result || !result?.ok) {
                localStorage.removeItem('info')
                setInfoStorage(undefined)
            }

            setInfoStorage(input)
            localStorage.setItem('info', 'input')
            setInput('')
        }, [input, result, getInfo, setInfoStorage, setInput])

        return (
            ...
            <Form onSubmit={handleInfoSubmit}>
                <input>
                ...
            </Form>
        )
    }
```

Basically, the user inserts a code in the form and when he submits the form, it runs the `handleInfoSubmit` function. Then, the code runs the function `getInfo()` and after requesting the API it returns the information to the state `result`.

The problem is in the `SomeComponent.tsx` file: when I run the function `getInfo(input)` I need the information in the state `result` but at the time axios finishes the request to the API and the code goes to the `if (!result || !result?.ok)` line, the `result` state is not still fulfilled.

I know that React/Gatsby can't update immediately the state like what I need, but is there a way to overcome this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the value of the `result` would always be stale inside the `handleInfoSubmit` function per your code.

Rewrite the `getInfo` and `handleInfoSubmit` like this

```js
// Return data from getInfo so that we can use the value directly in handleInfoSubmit
const getInfo = useCallback(async (value: string) => {
   const url = `<URL_FROM_API${value}>`
   try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(url);
      setResult(data)
      return data;
   } catch {
      setResult(null)
   }

   return null;
})
```

```js
const handleInfoSubmit = useCallback(async () => {
   // await getInfo and get the axios response data.
   const result = await getInfo(input)

   if (!result || !result?.ok) {
       localStorage.removeItem('info')
       setInfoStorage(undefined)
   }

   setInfoStorage(input)
   localStorage.setItem('info', 'input')
   setInput('')
}, [input, getInfo, setInfoStorage, setInput])
```

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly correct. It's easier than I thought. Thank you very much